# How to abort a install shield installation from Visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield

I install a exe in visual studio which is a part of installshield project. I need to check the existence of a registry and based on the result, I have to abort the installation of entire Installer. Is there any way to trigger the abort process in C#?

Comment: There's no need for that. You can check for prerequisite keys in the installer and tell the user that the installation can't proceed. That's part of Windows and MSI itself, not an InstallShield feature. If you want to check eg for the existence of a specific .NET Runtime or product, Installshield may already include it in a list of prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write any code for this. This is already a supported feature of windows-installer.

In Installshield, go to behavior and logic > System Search. Define a new system search.

Choose the Registry entry item.

[image]

Select the registry path and value for which you want to search.

[image]

Create any custom property here and check the radio box to **Store the value in property and use in Install condition.**

[image]

This is it.

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos for suggestion.

Comment: This one helped me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to achieve the same requirement in Advanced UI project of installshield?

Comment: Did you mean Installshield Suite project?

Comment: Yes, it is suite project

Comment: I guess exit conditions are there and events.

Comment: Yes, with event I can throw a an error and abort, but I need to check whether  a particular package is installed or not and based on that I need to abort the setup. Is there any way for this?